# registerForActivityResult not working when second activity orientation changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, kotlin-android-extensions, startactivityforresult

I am calling activity B from activity A using the `ActivityResultLauncher` and setting the result from activity B when the task is done. This works perfectly if orientation is not changed. The problem is when I change orientation from activity B and then setting the result, then `registerForActivityResult` of activity A is not called. Could someone let me know, what could be the issue?

Note: I do not face this issue if I am using `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`. I changed this to `ActivityResultLauncher` as `startActivityForResult` became [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha04).

activity A sample code:

```
private lateinit var launcher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout)
    setLauncherResult()
}

private fun setLauncherResult() {
    launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Do operations here
        }
}

 //On button click starting activity B using launcher
 val intent = Intent(activityA, activityB)
 launcher.launch(intent)

}
```

activity B sample code:

```
//setting result
val intent = Intent()
//set intent extras
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

Comment: can you link info that `startActivityForResult` is deprecated?

Comment: @snachmsm https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha04

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in `onSaveInstanceState()` and use setResult in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: value is already saved in onSaveInstanceState(). How can I do setResult in onRestoreInstanceState()? setResult is done on a keyboard done action in activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `registerForActivityResult` assignment of `launcher` to `onCreateView()`  (override it if you haven't already).  Putting it here, I'm not getting the "is attempting to register while current state is STARTED" `RuntimeException` in  `OnCreateView()` as it would with `onResume()` or later.  The advantage of `OnCreateView()` over `OnCreate()` seems to be that the `launcher` variable will get re-set on theme day/night changes as well as just orientation changes.

Also see the **Configuration change & Process death** section [here](https://kaustubhpatange.github.io/blog/post/kotlin-activity-result/) for more discussion.

I know [the official dox](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) say it's safe to set it before anything else in the class, but theme changes broke `.launch()`, and this location appears to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Everytime orientation changes it calls `onCreate` and  it resets your views & Other variables like `launcher` are re-assigned. So you can follow the example shown in official document here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch

And pull your `launcher` assignment out of `onCreate` as following (This worked for me):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    private val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //do your stuff here
            binding.tv.text = result.data?.getStringExtra("text")
        }
    }


    companion object {
        var number : Int = 0
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.tv.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
            startForResult.launch(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want that `onCreate` should be called again when orientation changes. Then in your Manifest you can add `configChanges`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```